# Add a brightness slider to the top bar? Using 5.1 Hera on a Surface Pro 2

Tags: brightness, release-hera

I would like to add a brightness slider to the top-bar, but am not able to figure out how to do this via System Settings -> Power -> Display Brightness. Unfortunately the SP2 keyboard does not have Fn buttons for this either.

I have tried this "Brightness Indicator" app, and it seemed to install fine, but it will not open:
[image]

EDIT: Never mind, found the brightness slider under the **Battery icon drop-down menu**. First day on the OS if you can't tell!

Comment: this is what I was going to answer you but it looks like you found it alone.) Can you add the **EDIT** like an answer and later accept it in order to be clear for all of us that this question is resolved before we read it?

Answer (score 1):

I found the brightness slider under the **Battery icon** drop-down menu:
[image: brightness_slider]